# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I am creating a React project using Typescript and I am creating it from scratch without CRA. But I am facing difficulties. I think the error is due to adding typescript and configuring webpack config file for it.
I am unable to find the error here. Please help. I am using typescript.

PFA code

**webpack.config.json**

Configuration file for webpack

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');


const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const mode = isProd ? 'production' : 'development';

const cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader'];
const cssProd = [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'];
const cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev;


const pluginDev = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.html'
    })
];

const pluginProd = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.html',
        minify: {
            removeAttributeQuotes: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
        }
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "css/[name].[contenthash].css"
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()];

const pluginConfig = isProd ? pluginProd : pluginDev;


const outputDev = {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
};
const outputProd = {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
};
const outputConfig = isProd ? outputProd : outputDev;

const optimizeProd = {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
      // `...`
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  };
const optimizeConfig = isProd ? optimizeProd : null;


module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: outputConfig,
    plugins: pluginConfig,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i, 
                use: cssConfig 
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: '[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
                        outputPath: "images"
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ],
      },
      devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
      },
}
```

**index.html**

Index file which has a div with an id root

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" conent="ie=edge" />
        <meta name="description" content="Airbnb clone without CRA" />
        <title>Scratch React Airbnb App</title>
        
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/ico/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/ico/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/ico/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="./assets/ico/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="./assets/ico/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00aba9">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Fonts.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- comment -->
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.tsx**

App file with typescript

```js
import React , {Suspense, lazy} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoadingScreen from './LoadingScreen';

const Home = lazy(() => import("./Home"));
const Explore = lazy(() => import("./Explore"));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import("./NotFound"));

const App: React.FC = () =>  {
    return (
        <main>
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                    <Route path="/explore" component={Explore} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </main>
    )
}

export default App
```

Thanks

Comment: The configuration looks ok. What problem are you facing though. You get a compilation error? You get a blank page when you serve the content? Any other errors ? Maybe also share `tsconfig.json` and your entry point `./src/index.tsx`

Comment: @kidroca I solved this issue with fonts, I included ttf format in webpack config file and it started to work. Thanks